# Selenium Passing String Characters in lowercase

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am passing the `UserName as MLKFT800` in the login form using the `sendkeys` method **but** sometimes this string is passed as `MLKft800`.I tried `String.uppercase()` as well but it is also not working.

Please suggest any solution.Thanks.

Comment: have u tried using .toUpperCase() method?

Comment: Please share your code.. what have you already done??

Comment: Can you share your code and the page on which you are working on ?

Comment: plz add what have you tried it will make everybody clear

Comment: Please find the code below ( I can not share the URL as it is not permitted to share ).   WebElement User_Id = driver.findElement(By.id("userID"));   User_Id.Sendkeys("MLKFT800");

Comment: I have also tried .toUpperCase Method but still sometimes it is passsing that one character as small.Thanks.

Comment: This is very strange.  Try doing User_id.clear() before the Sendkeys().  Maybe that will help.

Comment: You should try ==> JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", User_Id, "MLKFT800".toUpperCase());